SAP Split Valuation vs BWTAR field logic?
I'm creating a report on SAP Inventory - not by ABAP or any other native tool, I have instead a direct connection to the database and use an external tool.
The MBEW table has the following keys:

MANDT
MATNR
BWKEY
BWTAR

I know how to deal with the first 3, but I'm having a hard time with the last one. I got to understand that BWTAR is related to "Split Valuation": an item may have different value depending on various conditions, like e.g. whether it comes from Procurement or from Production. If Split Valuation is enabled, Inventory Movements are recorded at the Batch level, in table MCHB.
If I got it right, in any case stock is recorded in MBEW at the Valuation Area level (which roughly corresponds to the Plant level) and in MARD at the Inventory Location level, with the corresponding historical tables MBEWH and MARDH. MBEW has values in it, whilst MARD only has quantities. Conversely, it looks like records are put into MCHB only if the Item is managed in Batches and/or with Split Valuation.
I'm trying to report at the Inventory Location level, including value. If the Item is not Split Valued, this should be doable by joining MARD to MBEW and using the latter to catch the unit value. If the Item is Split Valued, it is necessary to look at MCHB joined to MCHA to understand what is the Valuation Type (BWTAR) for each Batch, and this gives the 4th key to lookup MBEW and get the unit value.
My first question is whether what I have written up to now is correct - but I should be able to check by testing. My real problem is instead: how do I figure out whether an Item is Split Valued? I see there is a field called BWTTY (Valuation Category) in MARC, replicated in MBEW, which is non empty when the Item is Split Valued; is that the right field to look at? And I found out that this field is not recorded in the history tables MARCH and MBEWH, which brings to my last (and most difficult, apparently) question: is it even possible for an Item to be Split Valued sometime in the past and not Split Valued in some other times?

BWTAR is a customizable field, therefore it depends on the customer configuration.

You'd better use native tools like modules

BAPI_MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY or
BAPI_MATERIAL_STOCK_REQ_LIST

Manully recreating the logic of the stock query is tricky and would be much more time-consuming than you think.
